# Generate dates between two dates in a dataframe

Tags: r

Below are the input and output. I want to transform a data frame from Input format to Output Format.

I have written a piece of code for now. it does the job. but I think it's very inefficient. are there any better packages or functions that can handle this?

mycode:

```
#create a output data frame to be apended later
output = data.frame(id1 = character(0), id2 = character(0), dates = character(0))

# for loop to get all possible combiation of dates

for (i in c(1:nrow(input))) {
  end  = as.Date('2016-07-18')
  len = as.numeric(end-input$min_date[i])
  output = rbind(output, as.data.frame(cbind(
    pid = rep(input$id1[i],len),
    cid = rep(input$id2[i],len),
    dates = as.character(seq(input$min_date[i], end, by='day'))
  )
  )
  )
```

}

Input:

```
+------+--------+------------+------------+
| id1  |  id2   |  min_date  |  max_date  |
+------+--------+------------+------------+
| 3575 | 155443 | 2012-06-18 | 2016-07-18 |
| 3575 | 155450 | 2012-06-12 | 2016-07-18 |
+------+--------+------------+------------+
```

output:

```
+------+--------+------------+
| id1  |  id2   |   dates    |
+------+--------+------------+
| 3575 | 155443 | 2012-06-18 |
| 3575 | 155443 | 2012-06-19 |
| 3575 | 155443 | 2012-06-20 |
| 3575 | 155443 | ..         |
| 3575 | 155443 | …          |
| 3575 | 155443 | 2016-07-18 |
|      |        |            |
| 3575 | 155450 | 2012-06-12 |
| 3575 | 155450 | 2012-06-13 |
| 3575 | 155450 | 2012-06-14 |
| 3575 | 155450 | …          |
| 3575 | 155450 | …          |
| 3575 | 155450 | 2016-07-18 |
+------+--------+------------+
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that the 'min_date/max_date' columns are `Date` class, we use `Map` to get the sequence of each 'min_date' with the corresponding 'max_date' in a `list`, replicate the sequence of rows of 'df1' with the number of rows of the `list` elements, create a `data.frame` by expanding the dataset based on 'i1' and get create 'dates' by concatenating the 'lst' elements.

```
lst <- Map(function(x, y) seq(x,y, by = "1 day"), df1$min_date, df1$max_date)
i1 <- rep(1:nrow(df1), lengths(lst)) 
data.frame(df1[i1,-3], dates = do.call("c", lst))
```

---

Or if we are using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   rowwise() %>% 
   do(data.frame(.[1:2], date = seq(.$min_date, .$max_date, by = "1 day")))
```

---

Or using `data.table`, we can do this in a single line of code

```
library(data.table) 
setDT(df1)[,.(date = seq(min_date, max_date, by = "1 day")) ,.(id1, id2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr` and `splitstackshape` packages,

```
library(dplyr)
library(splitstackshape)
df %>% 
   group_by(id1, id2) %>% 
   mutate(dates = paste(seq(as.Date(min_date),as.Date(max_date),by = 1), collapse = ',')) %>% 
   select(-c(min_date, max_date)) %>% 
   cSplit('dates', ',', 'long')
```